# How to make nodes line reader skip lines conditionally

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using a line reader to input credit card numbers into a validator and identifier. Lets say I input 10 numbers, and they are from four different credit card companies. I want to ignore three companies and only show the numbers from the remaining companies.

This companies rules (conditions) are that it must have 15 digits in it, and start with 37 or 34

```
4111111111111111
4111111111111
4012888888881881
378282246310005
6011111111111117
5105105105105100
5105105105105106
9111111111111111
371449635398431
378734493671000
```

Here is my current makeshift module:

```
export const isAmex = (creditCard: string): boolean =>
creditCard.length === 15 &&
(creditCard.substring(0, 2) === '37' || creditCard.substring(0, 2) === '34')

export const is2Amex = (creditCard: string): boolean =>
creditCard.length === 15 &&
(creditCard.substring(0, 2) === '37' || creditCard.substring(0, 2) === '34')

export const ifIsntAmex = (creditCard: string) => {
    if (!is2Amex(creditCard)) {
        return ' '
    } else {
        return creditCard
    }
}

export const getAmexName = (creditCard: string) => {
    if (!isAmex(creditCard)) {
        return ' '
    } else {
        return 'AMEX'
    }
}
```

Here is part of the index:

```
const outputAmex: string[] = []

lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
    outputAmex.push(
    `${getAmexName(creditCard)}: ${ifIsntAmex(creditCard)}  
    (${cardValidator(creditCard) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'})`
    )
})

lineReader.on('close', () => {
    fs.writeFile('./data/Amex.txt', outputAmex.join('\n'), err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('The file has been saved!')
    })
})
```

It returns something like this:

```
:   (valid)
:   (invalid)
:   (valid)
AMEX: 378282246310005 (invalid)
:   (valid)
:   (valid)
:   (invalid)
:   (invalid)
AMEX: 371449635398431 (invalid)
AMEX: 378734493671000 (invalid)
```

How would I ignore the non-Amex lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
  if (getAmexName(creditCard)) {
    outputAmex.push(
      `${getAmexName(creditCard)}: ${creditCard} (${
        cardValidator(creditCard) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
      })`
    )
  }
})
```

This is what worked for me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
   if (is2Amex(creditCard)) {
      outputAmex.push(); 
   }
})
```

something like that?